# Does Alpha Beta / minimax require that each node be a full copy of the gameboard?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, alpha, minimax, beta

This is not a language-specific question, but for the sake of conversation, I currently work in C# 7.

Over the years I've successfully implemented the Alpha Beta pruning algorithm (even in PASCAL, 35 years ago :)

Each time, I've created semi-deep-copies (discussed below) of the game state which is recursed for each node. I've often wondered if this is necessary and if perhaps I'm not truly understanding the algorithm.

The interweb is full of requests for help for TicTacToe, which makes me think that this must be a common school assignment question - which kinda clogs searches on this fairly basic topic.

**Semi-deep-copies** ... it appears to me that each node should know:

- the full state of the board
- the player whose turn it is
- the state of play - ie: { playing, Player1 win, Player2 win, draw }

My question is: **does each node need its own copy of the board**? ... for example Chess has 8x8 grid ... is there something more subtle to the algorithm, or do these nodes each need their own snap-shot of the board state? Is there some cool way (other than **copy** and apply-possible-move) that nodes can use to derive their state from their parent?

Perhaps someone can explain or point to a "read this, dummy" post, or just confirm that I need to make these instances, as I've attempted to describe, with each recursive call having its own in-memory copy of the game board.

I realize that over the last few decades, memory has become cheap... but combinatorial-explosion is still the main topic. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question. But could you instead of making a copy each turn do the move, make the recursive call, and then undo the move instead? Something like:

```
board.make_move(move)
eval = minimax(board, ....)
board.unmake_move(move)
```

Comment: I'll try this exact idea and let you know how it goes. Lovely concise answer that shows that you did indeed understand my (less-than-concise) question.

Comment: Glad to help! I know the struggle, I tried it with chess but I had too many rules in my move function which made it very complicated to make an unmake move function. Maybe I'll try again another time.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel like this is correct.

Comment: I did indeed ... back on Jan 13 but it won't appear until my rep goes above 15 (new user).